# Can't bind to a property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've got the following markup.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Address" 
         Text="{x:Static local:MainWindow.Boundie.SomeProp}" 
</TextBox>
```

In the code behind I have a static property like so.

```
static Something Boundie { get; set; }

public class Something { public String SomeProp { get; set; } }
```

The problem is that it nags that "type expected" when I hover over *Boundie* and "static member expected" when I hover over *SomeProp*. When I leave out the latter, it only complains that the expected type is *String* but it only sees *Something*.

How do I bind to a static member's non-static field?

Why I want to do that? Because I want to reuse the domain object model and those classes are not equipped with static members.

Comment: Why do you bind to statics at all? Shouldn't you bind to your viewmodel?

Comment: @nvoigt Good question. Because that'd require me to develop the whole view model. And since the DB schema's been rebuilt, that's a lot of work. And I'd like to show my customer this little behavior. The work on view model can be done at a later time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SomeProp` is instance property so you cannot use `x:Static` to access that. You can bind to it using combination of static `Source` and `Path`

```xml
<TextBox ...
         Text="{Binding 
           Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.Boundie}, 
           Path=SomeProp}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<object property="{x:Static prefix:typeName.staticMemberName}" .../>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx

Comment: The line above it contains the essentials.

Comment: It might very well be so but to someone who's still trying to get their bearings right in the binding swamp, it's kind of crypitically confusing. Not saying it's wrong or misleading. Just that I was doing more head-scratching than key-typing after I've read it.   :)